# Including output from another xsl from within an xsl processing

Tags: xslt

I am currently transferring a XML object to HTML using XSL 2.0. One of the field in my XML is an id for country. The id-label mapping for country code is defined in another XML (countries.xml) like:

```
<countries>
  <country id="1" name="United States of America"/>
  <country id="2" name="Canada"/>
</countries>
```

Is it possible to load the countries.xml and get country label for my id in my main XSL transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use either the `doc()` or `document()` function to open the XML file and build a tree of nodes.  The functions return the root node of the tree that is created and you get your information from there.

For completeness, your code would look something like the following, assuming you are looking up a value found in the variable `$findCode` you need only one declaration and one line in XSLT 2.0:

```
<xsl:key name="countries" match="country" use="@id"/>

...other code...

    <xsl:value-of select="key('countries',$findCode,document('countryCodes.xml'))/@name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using <xsl:apply-templates select="" mode="">

I created a separate countries.xsl file, like the one below and used <xsl:call-template name="countrySubstitution"> to invoke this.

In my main XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="country">
    <xsl:call-template name="countrySubstitution">
        <xsl:with-param name="contextName" select="@name"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

countries.xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">

    <xsl:template name="countrySubstitution">
        <xsl:param name="countryCode" select="."/>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('countries.xml')" mode="ABCD">
            <xsl:with-param name="countryCode" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/" mode="ABCD">
        <xsl:param name="countryCode" select="."/>
        <xsl:value-of select="//country[@id=$countryCode]/@name" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```